# How to make different WHERE clauses

Tags: php, mysql

```
$data['do'] = $this->db->query("SELECT MONTH(`date`) as month, COUNT(*) as count
FROM `simple` WHERE `ochistka` = 'somevalue' GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)");
```

Here i am selecting fields that have somevalue for each month, but how can i select one more field with others conditions, not like for the count(*) as count, but one more count(*) as count2, that have other WHERE clause is that possible?

Comment: Are you familiar with sub-queries? It's one way to get what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, you can use the SUM(IF) trick, something like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(`date`) as month,
       SUM(IF(`ochistka` = 'somevalue', 1, 0)) as count1,
       SUM(IF(`ochistka` = 'othervalue', 1, 0)) as count2
FROM `simple`
GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)
```

Comment: what mean the values 1, 0 - in the sum function?

Comment: BlareStriker: Quite simple, actually.  For each row, if the condition is met, then we use 1 for that row, otherwise we use 0.  When we sum these 1's and 0's, we get the count of rows where the condition was met.  Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: i have tried this code, but i get an error, i can't understand where i need to write the where condition?

Comment: @BlareStriker You don't need to write any `where` conditions: the condition is already inside the `if`

Comment: @BlareStriker Apologies for syntax error, left out extra parentheses.  I updated my answer.

Comment: why i get an error using your code,                                                                    SELECT MONTH(`date`) as month, SUM(IF `ochistka` = 'somevalue', 1, 0) as 'count1' FROM `simple` GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)

Answer (score 0):

Can't test the code right now, but the basic idea is to use subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.month as month, t1.count as count1, t2.count as count2 
FROM
    (SELECT MONTH(`date`) as month, COUNT(*) as count
     FROM `simple` 
     WHERE `ochistka` = 'somevalue' 
     GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)) AS t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MONTH(`date`) as month, COUNT(*) as count 
     FROM `simple` 
     WHERE `ochistka` = 'someothervalue' 
     GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)) AS t2 ON t1.month = t2.month
```

Comment: а если у меня 10 таких полей и мне нужно их выбрать разными WHERE, столько кода писать?, или лучше уже по отдельности писать для каждого поля??

Comment: @BlareStriker It's better to use English here so others could understand the discussion. Indeed, AleksG's answer is much more suitable in your case, but subqueries might be of sum use if you have more complex logic.

Comment: i can't understand why i get an error when i use their code SUM(IF `ochistka` = 'othervalue', 1, 0) as "count2" - what its wrong here?

Comment: For the sake of others reading this, translation of BlareStriker's comment: "And what if I have 10 such fields and I need to select them with different WHERE clauses, then how much code will need to be written?  Or is it better to write separate code for each field?"

Comment: @BlareStriker Apologies for syntax error, left out extra parentheses.  I updated my answer.